# How to write a macro that does malloc, formats a string and then returns the formatted string?

Tags: c, macros

I have tried this:

```
#define format(f, ...) \
                int size = strlen(f) + (sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__})/sizeof(int)) + 1); \
                char *buf = malloc(size); \
                snprintf(buf, size, f, __VA_ARGS__); \
                buf
```

But it returns a lot of syntactic errors. How do I do this properly?

Comment: Can I interject to say you really shouldn't do this for any reason other than learning how the C preprocessor works?

Comment: .. And also write down the exact errors you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C macros are not functions but 1:1 substitutions. So if you want to use your macro like this:

```
mystring = format("%d", 5);
```

You get this:

```
mystring = int size = strlen(f) + (sizeof((int[]){5})/sizeof(int)) + 1); \
            char *buf = malloc(size); \
            snprintf(buf, size, f, 5); \
            buf;
```

Which does not make any sense. In your case you are better off defining an inline function which should not be any worse in terms of performance on a decent compiler.

If it *really* has to be a macro and you are on GCC, you can use the compound statement to achieve your goal. It allows you to do this: `mystring = ({ statement1, statement2, ..., statementN})` which will execute all your statements in a local scope and then assign `statementN` to `mystring`. However it will make your code non-portable and be a hell to debug.

So here you go, but please don't use this in real applications:

```
#define format(f, ...) \
    ({ int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, f, __VA_ARGS__) + 1;\
    char * buf = malloc(size);\
    snprintf(buf, size, f, __VA_ARGS__); buf; })
```

I'm serious. Don't use this. Use an inline function. You can also have variadic arguments in normal functions, using `va_arg` and `va_start`:

```
inline char * format(f, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, f);
    int size = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, f, args) + 1;
    char * buf = malloc(size);
    vsnprintf(buf, size, f, args);
    return buf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this without an argument, you should type

```
snprintf(buf, size, f, ## __VA_ARGS__);
```

instead; else it won't truncate the trailing comma.

In addition, if you want to use a format string, you can't be sure that `strlen(format) + length of every other elements` is actually the size you get. You have to make an assumption then use a safe function.

Returning the value is also not possible using this kind of macro syntax. Using a GNU extension, however, is possible. See the modified answer below.

Also, what do you want to do with

```
sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__}
```

? It is not good at all. You can't find out the size of a variadic argument list.

Try something like this:

```
#define format(f, ...) \
            ({
            char *buf = malloc(4096); \
            snprintf(buf, 4096, f , ## __VA_ARGS__); \
            buf
        })
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: OP's code has much bigger problems than this, and your code is not even valid C..

Comment: you are using several gcc extensions, here. The OP didn't say anything about that specific compiler

Comment: Hm, I wrote that it's only possible with GNU extensions. Anyway, are there anybody who's using anything other than GCC for compiling C? Yes, there's LLVM-CLANG on OS X but it supports GNU extensions anyway.

Comment: @H2CO3 that's a very narrow view... there's also Visual C and the Intel C Compiler which are both used a lot.

Comment: That's true, but 1. Intel compilers support the vast majority of GNU extensions, 2. if you're complaining about me using GNU extensions, you'd better not mention Visual-C++, as it not simply "extends" the language but violates several standards so that most source that is compileable with GCC, Intel and several other (minor) compilers (sometimes even valid C89!) cannot be translated using VC++. **Also, in the user's question, the variadic macro in itself is a GNU extension.**

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you're trying to do with the first line. You seem to be trying to compute the number of arguments, but then you're passing that to `malloc` and using the return value of `malloc` as a size..?!

The correct way to allocate space for `snprintf` is to first call `snprintf` with the buffer pointer and size as zero, and inspect the return value. Adding one to the return value (for null termination) will give you the size you need to allocate and pass to the second `snprintf` call.

Also, don't try to do this with a macro; use a function and `vsnprintf`.